# Geting to have the appendix on all page widht just after the end of bibliography which is only on one column, all on the same page

Tags: bibliographies, two-column, appendices, appendix, column-width

I have the end of document with bibliography with 2 columns formatting.

Now, I would like to get, just after the end of left column bibliography, the appendix which covers the full width of page and which would be also on the same page (and not on another page created).

How could I find a trick that would allow me to have the end of bibliography and the beginning of appendix on full width on the same page ?

Here the Latex code that I have tried :

```
\bibliography{references}

%\nobreak
%\balance


\clearpage
\onecolumn 
\nopagebreak


\begin{appendix}
\section*{Appendix}
\noindent Demonstration of variance \operatorname{Var}(\hat{o})
```

But it doesn't work, any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Use [multicol](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en) for your references?